# Как написать геттер для массива

Tags: c++, массивы, getter

Допустим есть у меня класс точки:

```
class Point {
public :
    double x, y;
    static double Distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
        return sqrt(pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
    }
};
```

и класс треугольника который описывается тремя точками:

```
class Triangle {
private:
    Point points[3];
    double perimeter;
public :
    Triangle(Point points[3])
    {
        SetPoints(points);
    }

    void SetPoints(Point points[3]) {
        this->points[0] = points[0];
        this->points[1] = points[1];
        this->points[2] = points[2];

        perimeter = Point::Distance(points[0], points[1]) +
            Point::Distance(points[0], points[2]) +
            Point::Distance(points[1], points[2]);
    }

    double GetPerimeter() {
        return perimeter;
    }
};
```

Как правильно написать геттер для массива `points`?
Ведь если просто вернуть указатель на первый элемент массива то тогда значения массива можно будет изменять вне класса, и может сложится ситуация когда значения `perimeter` будет не правильным.

Comment: разве? Ты проверял?

Comment: @Данил Да, только что проверил. Координаты меняются, а периметр остается тем же.

Comment: А **зачем** вам этот геттер? Это не стеб, а повод задуматься.

Comment: @Harry Конкретно в этом примере - незачем, но это только пример.

Comment: @Harry Но допустим что мне надо геттер для того чтобы получить координаты чтобы потом нарисовать треугольник на экране.

Comment: *"Ведь если просто вернуть указатель на первый элемент массива то тогда значения массива можно будет изменять вне класса"* Ну так возвращате указатель на константу: `const Point *`.

Comment: Но зачем именно как массив? Можно вернуть, например, сами значения. Ну, или воспользуйтесь советом @HolyBlackCat - но в этом случае вы по сути теряете преимущества инкапсуляции, вынося внутреннее устройство класса наружу.